# Can't connect to a database with another user

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql, and I have a database named `django_db` and a user `manuel`. I want to connect to this database by this user, I tried this `\c django_db manuel` but I get this error:

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "manuel"
Previous connection kept
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user `manuel` has access to the database `django_db` in the [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file, e.g.

```
host django_db manuel your_ip_adress md5
```

Or if you prefer to give this user access to all databases

```
host all  manuel   your_ip_adress md5
```

After modifying your `pg_hba.conf` you have to either restart postgres or simply reload the file using the following [`function`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE):

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a user mapping in place, only the OS user named 'manuel' can connect as the PostgreSQL user named 'manuel'.  This is what "peer authentication" means.

You have many choices here.  Try this as an OS user named 'manuel', or change from peer to some other type of authentication (in pg_hba.conf), or create a pg_ident.conf file (and then configure pg_hba.conf to use it) that allows the OS user you actually are to login as PostgreSQL user 'manuel'.